# Which RF transceiver to use for a network using Rpi or Arduino?

Tags: networking, wifi, arduino, radio, pi-zero

I am looking for advice on how to create a RF network to send and receive data both at the same time.  The master Arduino or Rpi Zero receives temperature readings from the slave nodes which passes it to a Rpi to upload to a web interface.
And the opposite happens for a command e.g. light on. I have already done the pi side as i have developed the web interface.

How would i get over the interference between the modules operating on the same frequency?
So a message transmited by one receiver would be picked up by the other receivers  in the other nodes but not the receiver in the node that it is sent from.

I plan to append a sensor id so it only gets acted on by one node as the messages will be filtered.Either with an if statement. So it will scan every message it picks up for a destination id and if it is equal to its node id it will act on it overwise it will ignore it. It will all be in one building

My string formula  for transmission will be "255:Sender Node id:Destination Id: command codes e.g. 02 to switch on relay: Sensor values"

The range must be 100m (through thick walls and up a floor)

I want to keep cost low but not to buy of eBay because i want proper documentation and quick delivery times.

It must be an easy platform where the heavy lifting, through a library is done for me, it must be compatible with Arduino or Rpi

Should i use Rpi zero or Arduino clone as the slaves and the master ( the nodes will need to measure the voltage which is mains).

Sorry if unclear as i am confused.

Any other issues i need too worry about?
Should i consider WiFi?
Thanks in advance
Daniel

Comment: The sum of your cost, delivery, and ease of use requirements probably does not exist.  Something like nrf24L01's with the outboard power amp might do it with an error correcting protocol, but you won't get that version inexpensively from a 2-day supplier.  You could perhaps use the cheap plain ones if you setup a mesh networking scheme to aid with the distance, but at minimum that is going to have you digging into interesting libraries, if not working on the details yourself.

Comment: As interesting as your question is, it is really opinion based and you are asking for purchase recommendations. You should do your own research and contact vendors and decide for your self which one will be the best. There is a whole lot of stuff happening in your question... and it is not even relating to Raspberry Pi, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi might not give you the range you require. Each transmitter would need a unique ID. [These products here](http://www.sf-innovations.co.uk/dual_analogue_radio_transmitter.html) meet some (but not all) of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use APC220 module, if connecting to arduino, use the TX RX pins. I have two of those and can expect range up to 500 meters.
I think it must be compatible with Rpi if you get a TTL to USB adapter.
And to use nodes, use if statement, so that if node 1 wants to talk to node 5, send a message like
 `5.message here`
And the node 5 only receives messages if starting with `5.`
And yes it can send and receive

Comment: Does it work with multiple pairs talking to each other 2 way. so transceiver in pair a can talk to the transceiver in pair b and vice versa. Just to confirm it is a transceiver and does 2 way comms

Comment: Transceivers, means, it sends and receives. So yes, you can have a 100 of these and if 1 transmits 99 will receive. How you handle the messages is up to you, but it seems like you have that worked out already. These are not cheap though, I have seen much  cheaper ones,albeit on eBay.